# For some profiles a quick action layout is showing the fields present in compact layout

Tags: quickaction, custom-profile, flexipages, compact-layout

I have added a new quick action with one formula field on account object. The formula field is exposed on the Flexipage.

But, for some profiles the layout expose fields present in compact layout.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The type of Quick action that you are using might be Update a record and your profile must have the edit permission missing for that profile that is why that quick action is not coming up. You can try giving edit access for Account object for that profile.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).